# Snapshot Replication where Publisher is SQL Server 2008 and Subscriber is SQL Server 2019 not working

Tags: sql-server, replication

​When we are performing Snapshot replication where Publisher is SQL Server 2008 and Subscriber is SQL Server 2019. We are receiving below mentioned errors.

Error messages: The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."Car"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20037 metadata query failed Invalid character value for cast specification (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 22018) Get help: http://help/22018 Unspecified error

When we change compatability level of subscriber database to 120 then snapshot replication is working successfully.

Is there anyway by which we can perform snapshot replication successfully without changing the compatability level?.

Answer (score 0):

The replication version compatibility rules are documented here: [Replication Backward Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15) (snapshot falls under Transactional Replication).

SQL Server 2008 is out of support, and replication between SQL 2008 and SQL 2019 is unsupported. So probably not.

Comment: Browne Thanks for response
Now I understood it.

Comment: @AbhishekModgi it looks as tho your accounts got split. You can use the link here https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to get in touch with the community team to let them help you connect them!